# ODE rates of change — units of time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Sorry, really dense question (you know when you've been looking at something too long and nothing makes sense anymore...?

I have an ODE model (a standard SIR for the epidemiology of a disease) in which all parameters operate with respect to time in months. A parameter in the literature, however, presents a parameter (infection rate) as the rate of infections per year (10 new infections/year). How do I make that a rate per month? Am I correct in thinking it's $10^{1/12} = 1.212$ infections per month?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct. Another way of thinking about this problem is just by converting the units.

$$r = 10 \dfrac{\text{infections}}{\text{year}}=10\dfrac{\text{infections}}{12\text{month}}=\frac{10}{12}\dfrac{\text{infections}}{\text{month}}$$